# Which its the subgroup generated by -1 respect to +?

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

I have the question: 
Which its the cyclic subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by -1 respect to +? I know that its all $\mathbb{Z}$ but I don´t understad why? 
Help, please.

Comment: Look at the definition of "(cyclic) subgroup generated by", and the answer will probably reveal itself.

Comment: @Arthur my problem probably is the notation, I can´t see how -1 can generate positive integers

Comment: For $n$ positive you have that $n = (-1)-(-1)-\underbrace{(-1)-\dots - (-1)}_{n~\text{times}}$

Comment: You can add *or subtract* the generator however many times as is necessary.

Comment: In general if you're given the generator of a group it's assumed that the inverse of that generator is also in the group. In this case $1$ is the inverse of $-1$ and $1$ clearly generates $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField If one is unclear how $-1$ could generate positive numbers, then one is equally unclear how $1$ could generate negative numbers. So your conclusion "and $1$ clearly generates $\Bbb Z$" is, in this case, circular logic.

Comment: @Arthur It wasn't meant to be rigorous just informational since forgetting the inverse is generating sets is a common error.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

The subgroup generated $-1$ is all integer multiples of $-1.$ Do you see why that's the case? If you cannot see it, please read the definition again.

Answer (score 0):

To my taste, a more positive way to think about "subgroup generated by subset $S$ of group $G$" is *not* to declare that it is the collection of all expressions involving elements of $S$ (and their inverses!), but, rather, that it is the "smallest subgroup of $G$ containing the set $S$". That there exists a smallest such subgroup, and that it is unique, is by observing that the *intersection* of all subgroups containing $S$ is a subgroup, contains $S$, and is a subgroup of any subgroup containing $S$.

So, in the case at hand, since "the subgroup generated by $-1$" (or, similarly, by $1$) first of all needs to be a subgroup, it has to contain additive inverses... so if it contains $-1$ it must contain $+1$, and vice versa. "Rules" about allowable expressions are secondary.